# Splitting a grid into manageable lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to split a grid as follows:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

What I ideally want is a format where each element can be easily accessed. I've been toying with combinations of `split` but it's not proving useful so far. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly `class Grid`? and define a `get(x,y)` function? What do you mean "split"?

Comment: What do you mean by "a format where each element can be easily accessed"? How is the elements of the structure you already have not "easily accessed"? What are you going to do with this grid?

Comment: In what way are the lists you already have _not_ manageable?

Comment: I was overanalyzing this problem. Got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already easily access any element of grid using 2 indexes.

```
grid[0][0]
```

would be the first element of the first row for example.

Comment: Simple is beautiful. Completely forgot that :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use a dictionary whose keys were tuples. This would allow you to access its elements with `grid[row, column]`. Here's one way to create and initialize it:

```
data = """\
    ......
    .OO...
    OOOO..
    OOOOO.
    .OOOOO
    OOOOO.
    OOOO..
    .OO...
    ......
"""

# Create dictionary from data list.
grid = {}
for i, row in enumerate(line.strip() for line in data.splitlines()):
    for j, elem in enumerate(row):
        grid[i, j] = elem

print('Access each element of the grid:')
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(6):
        print('grid[{}, {}] = {!r}  '.format(i, j, grid[i, j]), end='')
    print()
```

Output:

```
Access to each element of grid:
grid[0, 0] = '.'  grid[0, 1] = '.'  grid[0, 2] = '.'  grid[0, 3] = '.'  grid[0, 4] = '.'  grid[0, 5] = '.'  
grid[1, 0] = '.'  grid[1, 1] = 'O'  grid[1, 2] = 'O'  grid[1, 3] = '.'  grid[1, 4] = '.'  grid[1, 5] = '.'  
grid[2, 0] = 'O'  grid[2, 1] = 'O'  grid[2, 2] = 'O'  grid[2, 3] = 'O'  grid[2, 4] = '.'  grid[2, 5] = '.'  
grid[3, 0] = 'O'  grid[3, 1] = 'O'  grid[3, 2] = 'O'  grid[3, 3] = 'O'  grid[3, 4] = 'O'  grid[3, 5] = '.'  
grid[4, 0] = '.'  grid[4, 1] = 'O'  grid[4, 2] = 'O'  grid[4, 3] = 'O'  grid[4, 4] = 'O'  grid[4, 5] = 'O'  
grid[5, 0] = 'O'  grid[5, 1] = 'O'  grid[5, 2] = 'O'  grid[5, 3] = 'O'  grid[5, 4] = 'O'  grid[5, 5] = '.'  
grid[6, 0] = 'O'  grid[6, 1] = 'O'  grid[6, 2] = 'O'  grid[6, 3] = 'O'  grid[6, 4] = '.'  grid[6, 5] = '.'  
grid[7, 0] = '.'  grid[7, 1] = 'O'  grid[7, 2] = 'O'  grid[7, 3] = '.'  grid[7, 4] = '.'  grid[7, 5] = '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code which works:

```
grid = input("Enter list elements separated by comma ")
n_row,n_col = len(grid),len(grid[0])
for i in range(0,n_col):
    for j in range(0,n_row):
        print(grid[j][i],end='')
    print('\n')
```